# ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I'm trying to use API made with `Apollo GraphQL` and update `react` component realtime with the help of GraphQL subscriptions using `subscriptions-transport-ws` library. For **delete** operation, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements` error. Here's code from react component that is trying to update data from subscription.

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (!this.subscription && !nextProps.data.loading) {
                let { subscribeToMore } = this.props.data
                this.subscription = [subscribeToMore(
                {
                    document: postDeleted,
                    updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
                     const delPost = subscriptionData.data.postDeleted;
                     const mainData = previousResult.Posts;               

                     let post = mainData.find(post => post.id == delPost.id);
                     let updatedList =  mainData.splice(post, 1);
                     return updatedList;
                    },
                }
                )]
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`mainData` is most likely "[sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)" so your `splice` operation is throwing the error:

```
let updatedList =  mainData.splice(post, 1);
```

The solution is to make a copy of the array (using array destructuring here):

```
let updatedList = [...mainData].splice(post, 1);
```

You can try this out in Chrome console like so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
Object.seal(a);
a.splice(1)

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements
//  at Array.splice (<anonymous>)
//  at <anonymous>:1:3

[...a].splice(1)

// [2, 3]
```

Comment: splice returns the removed element so:
    let updatedList = [...mainData].splice(post, 1);
will not give you the updated list, but the single element that was removed

Comment: @Will [1,2,3].splice(1) (remove all after index "1") and [1,2,3].slice(1) (start at index 1 and return through end of sequence) both return [2,3] because of how deleteCount param in splice works.

Answer (score 1):

If your array has been sealed, you can make a copy of it and filter out the one you don't want like this:

`let updatedList = mainData.filter(post => post.id !== delPost.id);`